# How can I pass multiple function overloads as a single argument?

Tags: c++, templates, macros

This is another case of trying to get rid of a macro. Consider

```
void f_(int i) { printf("f_(int)\t%d\n", i); }
void f_(int i, double x) { printf("f_(int, double)\t%d, %5.3f\n", i, x); }
void g_(int i) { printf("g_(int)\t%d\n", i); }
void g_(int i, double x) { printf("g_(int, double)\t%d, %5.3f\n", i, x); }
```

(Imagine `f_()` gets data form a **.foo** file or uses hard-coded "dummy" values, `g_()` does the same for **.bar**.)  There might be a function to decide which overload to call:

```
void f(int i, double d) { (i > 0) ? f_(i, d) : f_(i); }
```

with the same logic duplicated for `g_()`:

```
void g(int i, double x) { (i > 0) ? g_(i, x) : g_(i); }
```

Getting rid of that duplicated code is easy with a macro:

```
#define h(i, x, func_) (i > 0) ? func_(i, x) : func_(i);
// ...
h(-1, 314.1, f_);
h(99, 314.1, f_);
h(-1, 314.1, g_);
h(99, 314.1, g_);
```

But of course we'd rather not use macros in C++.  The "obvious" template

```
template<typename T>
void h2(int i, double x, T t)
{
   (i > 0) ? t(i, x) : t(i);
}
// ...
h2(-1, 314.1, f_);
```

fails because the compiler can't figure out what overload of `f_()` to use.

How can I replace the functionality of the macro `h`?

Comment: you cant, at least not directly. What about passing an object that encapsulates the overloads?

Comment: wait a sec.. you want to pick the right overload and pass only this? or pass something and only inside `h2` pick the right overload?

Comment: @user463035818 The OP wants to pass the whole overload set so they can have `(i > 0) ? func_(i, x) : func_(i);` inside the function.

Comment: Are we correct to assume that the other arguments are not compile-time constants? Also, can you change the `f_` etc.?

Comment: @Ðаn Ok, next time that would be very useful information to add to the question (both what can and can't be changed). All answers had to take a shot in the dark.

Comment: maybe you can use a macro to define `f` and `g`, client only calls this two functions. so there is no macro on client side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't mind changing the definition's of `f_` and `g_`, you can do something like

```
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;

auto f_ = overloaded(
  [](int i) { printf("f_(int)\t%d\n", i); },
  [](int i, double x) { printf("f_(int, double)\t%d, %5.3f\n", i, x); }
);

auto g_ = overloaded(
  [](int i) { printf("g_(int)\t%d\n", i); },
  [](int i, double x) { printf("g_(int, double)\t%d, %5.3f\n", i, x); }
);
```

Then your `h` template is exactly what you want

```
template<typename T>
void h(int i, double x, T t)
{
   i > 0 ? t(i, x) : t(i);
}
```

The `overloaded` template shamelessly copied from [this example for `std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit).

[To make it work for C++11](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5iNO3I20EcHAREEa), you have to adapt the `overloaded` template and add a helper function to deduce the type parameters

```
template<class... Ts> struct overloads;
template<> struct overloads<>{};
template<class T, class... Ts> struct overloads<T, Ts...> : T, overloads<Ts...> 
{ 
    overloads(T t, Ts... ts) : T(t), overloads<Ts...>(ts...) {}
    using T::operator(); 
};

template<class... Ts> overloads<Ts...> overloaded(Ts&&... ts) 
{ return overloads<Ts...>(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...); }
```

Comment: @Ðаn the trick is making a single object rather than a single name. I just remember the `std::variant` example as a useful pattern

Comment: @rustyx Before C++17 you can just use a `makeOverloaded` function instead of deduction guides, no?

Comment: @rustyx I think you can make a C++11 variation, it'll just involve a `make_` function rather than a deduction guide

Comment: @Caleth … but the `using ...` can be avoided with [recursive inheritance](https://godbolt.org/g/SBxnHv). I also took the liberty of enabling stateful lambdas by adding constructors.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a variadic lambda and have the lambda call the function you wish to call.

```
template<typename T>
void h2(int i, double x, T t)
{
   i > 0 ? t(i, x) : t(i);
}

int main()
{
    h2(-1, 314.1, [](auto... args){ f_(args...); });
    //                              ^^ change this to g_ if you want to use g_ instead of f_
}
```

Comment: @Ðаn Yeah.  I was trying to come up with something that had the least amount of changes to your code.  I think Caleth's refactoring would be the best idea if you want the call site to stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it directly, because the type infered for `T` would need to include the parameter types, but you can do something along the line of

```
#include <iostream>
 
struct overloader {
    void foo(int) { std::cout << "int\n";}
    void foo(double) { std::cout << "double\n";}
};
 
template <typename T>
void bar(int x,double y,bool opt, T t){
    if (opt) { t.foo(x); }
    else { t.foo(y); }
}
      
int main() {
    overloader ol;
    bar(1,1,true,ol);
    bar(1,1,false,ol);
}
```

prints:

> int
>
> double